# Yii: Unexpected invocation of CHttpSession::close when running a method in custom class

Tags: php, yii

strange problem here. Using Yii framework I have the following class

```
class HtmlTableUi
{
  public function __construct(CWebModule &$module,$data,$actions) 
  {
    //...code goes here...
  }

  protected function renderTable() 
  {
    //... code goes here ...
  }
}
```

I can call HtmlTableUi::renderTable() from instance of HtmlTableUi in SchedulerModule class which is the main class in a separate application module. My SchedulerModule.php file:

```
<?php

Yii::import('scheduler.components.HtmlTableUi');

class SchedulerModule extends CWebModule
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
    }

    public function beforeControllerAction($controller, $action)
    {
        return true;
    }


    public function printUI($data,$actions,$submitPath)
        {
        $ui = new HtmlTableUi($this,$data,$actions,$submitPath);
        $ui->renderTable();
    }
}
```

Here comes the tricky part - when I call SchudulerModule::printUI from view (index.php) this way

```
<?php
    $this->module->printUI($casino,$actions,null);
?>
```

the code flow goes through SchudulerModule::printUI until reaching the point where **renderTable** is invoked ($ui->renderTable();) and instead stepping at the first line inside the body of that method it, contrary to any logic and rules, surprisingly jumps to **CHttpSession::close** !!?

Notice the **Call Stack** before invoking **renderTable**

```
protected/modules/scheduler/SchedulerModule.php.SchedulerModule->printUI:153    
protected/modules/scheduler/views/default/index.php.require:21  
/home/default/workspace/src/vlt/web/yii-1.1.12.b600af/framework/web/CBaseController.php.CBaseController->renderInternal:127 
/home/default/workspace/src/vlt/web/yii-1.1.12.b600af/framework/web/CBaseController.php.CBaseController->renderFile:96  
/home/default/workspace/src/vlt/web/yii-1.1.12.b600af/framework/web/CController.php.CController->renderPartial:870  
/home/default/workspace/src/vlt/web/yii-1.1.12.b600af/framework/web/CController.php.CController->render:783 
protected/modules/scheduler/controllers/DefaultController.php.DefaultController->actionIndex:57
```

and after:

```
/home/default/workspace/src/vlt/web/yii-1.1.12.b600af/framework/web/CHttpSession.php.CHttpSession->close:134    
/home/default/workspace/src/vlt/web/yii-1.1.12.b600af/framework/web/CHttpSession.php.SchedulerModule->printUI:0
protected/modules/scheduler/views/default/index.php.require:21  
/home/default/workspace/src/vlt/web/yii-1.1.12.b600af/framework/web/CBaseController.php.CBaseController->renderInternal:127 
/home/default/workspace/src/vlt/web/yii-1.1.12.b600af/framework/web/CBaseController.php.CBaseController->renderFile:96  
/home/default/workspace/src/vlt/web/yii-1.1.12.b600af/framework/web/CController.php.CController->renderPartial:870  
/home/default/workspace/src/vlt/web/yii-1.1.12.b600af/framework/web/CController.php.CController->render:783 
protected/modules/scheduler/controllers/DefaultController.php.DefaultController->actionIndex:57
```

Has anyone had similar issue? Can anyone explain that behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!!! The access modifier of *renderTable* is supposed to be **public**, not **protected**. This wrong somehow in Yii framework results in unexpected runtime behavior instead of compilation error.

Comment: No error message, no nothing ... like everything is working ok, except an unexpected behavior of the application.

Comment: Perhaps you have no `error_reporting` or `display_errors` set to `off`, php should display error about accessing protected method. `CHttpSession` `close` is invoked on errors too.

Comment: usually, my php displays exceptions. I'll check later. Thanks for suggestion :)

Comment: Checked! Yes, one the following flags was disabled: ini_set("display_errors", 1); ini_set("track_errors", 1); ini_set("html_errors", 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);